# prevent click event of listview when check box is checked in c#

Tags: c#

I have a list box with check box in it. but when i checked or unchecked the check box , list view click event is fired. I want to prevent click event when check box is checked or unchecked.

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: Can you show your markup and your code-behond?

Comment: Have you tried google it?

Comment: Do you have any requirement/need for listview_click event? Else disable the click event, it will serve your purpose

Answer (score 1):

What if you set the `EventArgs` object Handled to true in the Check Box click handler code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to actually prevent the event from firing is to go into the generated code and comment out the line that wires up the event handler for check box control inside of the listview, like this:

```
this.checkBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.checkBox_Click);
```

Either remove the above line(s) or comment them out.

Beware, that this code will, potentially, be regenerated by the designer so you may have to routinely check that the code is not recreated for you.